# Attempting to trigger automation tests via command line but seeing 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG'

Tags: java, windows, automation, automated-tests, testng

I'am attempting to trigger my tests via command line via the following command (I'm using a Windows 10 Operating System):

```
java -cp selenium-docker.jar:selenium-docker-tests.jar:libs/* -DBROWSER=firefox org.testng.TestNG ../search-module.xml
```

When running the following command I can see the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG
```

search-module.xml file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="search-module">
    <test name="search-test-java">
        <parameter name="keyword" value="java" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.searchmodule.tests.SearchTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="search-test-webdriver">
        <parameter name="keyword" value="webdriver" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.searchmodule.tests.SearchTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="search-test-docker">
        <parameter name="keyword" value="docker" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.searchmodule.tests.SearchTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="search-test-kubernetes">
        <parameter name="keyword" value="kubernetes" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.searchmodule.tests.SearchTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Java Version:

```
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I can see the testng jar listed within my target directory:
[image]

Project Structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your statement:

> I'm using a Windows 10 Operating System

your approach to define [CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) is wrong as on Windows:

1. PATH entries should be separated with semicolon `;`
2. File separator on Windows is backslash `\`

So theoretically you need to amend your [command to kick off TestNG suite](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/TestNG) to look like:

```
java -cp selenium-docker.jar;selenium-docker-tests.jar;libs/* -DBROWSER=firefox org.testng.TestNG ..\search-module.xml
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt comment, unfortunately still getting the same exception message :/ any ideas on anything else which I can try?

Comment: Also tried on two separate machines and two different projects still face the same issue, possibly an issue with Java 11.0.2?